# updating the XML when updating magento files

Tags: php, xml, magento

This piece of code is in **header.phtml**.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

But I want to move it to a different file and have it generate somewhere else, namely in the **..page/1column.phtml** and the **3columns.phtml** etc.

So I copy and paste it, but it doesn't appear :(

I am guessing that its something to do with the XML files, and I watched a few vids to learn about it, so I understand that its like html, but what I don't understand is how it is being used in magento exactly, or what the process would be to alter it

Do I copy and edit the originals, or put something into my own **local.xml** file?

Please can someone explain what is going on, or point me towards some content that explains this XML usage.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043387/magento-insert-block-into-another-without-change-template-code

Comment: go through the below link. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates

Comment: i needed this code here, and didnt need to touch xml files in the end <?=$this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml()?>

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it works, however I tend to try and keep all my updates through the local.xml file when possible.  It keeps all of your changes centralized and easier to track.

First you need to create or update your local.xml file  IF you do not have a local.xml file you can create one in

app->frontend->[Package Name]->[Theme Name]->layout->local.xml

Once this is created you can copy exactly what I have in this post into that file for a start of how to use one.

DO ALL UPDATES THROUGH A LOCAL.XML file not through page/catalog/checkout.xml etc !! This will make upgrades significantly easier later down the road.  Additionally, you will be able to quickly see all changes you have made to your site in one file.

The below example will add it to the root reference name which will be available on all pages but easily called in template->page->1column.phtml or 2column-left.phtml 3column.phtml etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
        </reference>
   </default>
</layout>
```

Then call it using the way that you currently are using.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

Now you can use the "reference name"  and  "as" name like the above section. For example you could use the similar setup below to reference the footer block to add the search feature. For education "as" names are what are used in .phtml files. and "name" is how a block is referenced within xml files.  So in the above example.  I am adding the search field to the root content area and then calling it in my .phtml file with the "as" name of "topLinks"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Then call it in footer.phtml with

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

Hope this helps!!   Any questions please feel free to ask!!  Regardless,  if you don't decide to use this method this time.  Hopefully it helps teach a little about how the local file works.